# Определение мобильного устройства, юзающего вап-сайт

Tags: php

Есть мобильная версия сайта. Нужно сделать условие: если человек открывает сайт с обычного телефона, то показать ему одну версию сайта; а если с apple, android - то другую версию. У кого-нибудь есть решение?

Answer (score 4):

Проверяйте **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']** если в строке есть **iphone** или **ipod** значит яблочник, если **android** то гуглофон.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$mobile = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mobile");
$symb = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Symbian");
$operam = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Opera M");
$htc = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"HTC_");
$fennec = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Fennec/");
$winphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"WindowsPhone");
$wp7 = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"WP7");
$wp8 = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"WP8");
if ($ipad || $iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $mobile || $symb || $operam || $htc || $fennec || $winphone || $wp7 || $wp8 === true) {
    header('Location: http://m.site.ru'); 
}

?>
```

Может так?

Comment: Очень радует строгое сравнение последнего элемента с true

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function pda(){
  $pda_patterns = array(
    'MIDP','FLY-','MMP','Mobile','MOT-',
    'Nokia','Obigo','Panasonic','PPC',
    'ReqwirelessWeb','Samsung','SEC-SGH',
    'Smartphone','SonyEricsson','Symbian',
    'WAP Browser','j2me','BREW', 'iPod', 'iPhone'
  );
  $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $user_agent = strtolower($agent);
  foreach($pda_patterns as $val){
    $val = strtolower($val);
    if(strpos($user_agent, $val) !== false){ return true; }
  }
  return false;
}
?>
```